Terraform root module with no default provider and child module with default
I have a top-level root module with no default AWS provider. Then I have a child module with a default provider and an alias. The setup is therefore a bit as below.
Root module:
provider "aws" {
  alias = "foo"
  ...
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "bar"
  ...
}

module "child" {
  providers = { aws = aws.foo, aws.second = aws.bar }
}

child module:
terraform {
  required_version = "1.9.1"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.67"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws.second ]
    }
  }
}

My child module has resources that do not specify the provider. I was assuming that it would use the default provider passed to it, i.e. aws.foo in that case. However, it looks like I instead get an error about no default provider in the root module.
I know the root module is also implicitly passed if I create resources without an explicit provider, so is there an issue here that it also tries to pass it implicitly and therefore fails as there's not default provider in the root, which to me would sound like a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Error is:
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the provider's required arguments as
│ described in the provider documentation.


Any reason not to use a provider in the root module?

What is the actual error message?

@MarkoE: Reason is to avoid excessive refactoring when updating terraform. This code used to work with an old terraform version using the legacy provider stuff.
